# Detect more than one face OpenCV

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

i'm learning python so i'm trying to work with OpenCV.
Program detecting only one face, if there will be 2 faces it will be show only one
here's the code:

```
def getData(id):
    psg = psgconnect.cursor()
    psg.execute("SELECT name FROM people WHERE id=%s", (Id,))
    cursor = psg.execute("SELECT name FROM people WHERE id=%s", (Id,))
    Data = None
    psgconnect.commit()
    row = psg.fetchone()
    #psgconnect.close()
    return row

while True:
    ret, img = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face = faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for(x, y, w, h) in face:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        Id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])
        data = getData(Id)
     #   if data != None:
    if(conf<50):
        #cv2.putText(img, data[0], (x, y + h), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (255, 255, 255), 4)
        cv2.putText(img, 'nashel', (x, y + h), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (255, 255, 255), 4)
    elif(conf>51):
        cv2.putText(img, 'Unknown', (x, y + h), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (255, 255, 255), 4)
    cv2.imshow("Face", img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    print("suda doshli")
    if k == 27:
        #psg.close()
        psgconnect.close()
        print("zdes")
    break
cam.release()
input()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What wroung could be?

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code, e.g. the `return` in the middle of your method that will make the following code unreachable, indentation problems (no indented group after the while, the break is not in a loop), etc. Please fix your code if the format is not the one you use and provide any error message ?

Comment: i posted from notepad so stackoverflow writed that it is has indents and proposed other variant. i will try to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not getting any answer, I'll try and help you even though I don't use OpenCV.

First, are you sure that OpenCV is only detecting one face in a two-face image or could it be a problem with your loop ?

You could check how many faces are detected by using a simple `print`:

```
ret, img = cam.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
face = faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
print len(face)
```

If it prints 1, then there actually is a problem with how OpenCV is working with your image (and in this case I really can't help you because I don't know anything about OpenCV). However, when I read your code, I get the feeling that some things are off (even after your edit), so I propose you tried the following:

```
def getData(id):
    psg = psgconnect.cursor()
    psg.execute("SELECT name FROM people WHERE id=%s", (Id,))
    cursor = psg.execute("SELECT name FROM people WHERE id=%s", (Id,))
    Data = None
    psgconnect.commit()
    row = psg.fetchone()
    #psgconnect.close()
    return row

while True:
    ret, img = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face = faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for(x, y, w, h) in face:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        Id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])
        data = getData(Id)
        if(conf<50):
            cv2.putText(img, 'nashel', (x, y + h), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (255, 255, 255), 4)
        elif(conf>51):
            cv2.putText(img, 'Unknown', (x, y + h), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (255, 255, 255), 4)
    cv2.imshow("Face", img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    print("suda doshli")
    if k == 27:
        #psg.close()
        psgconnect.close()
        print("zdes")
        break
cam.release()
input()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Let me know how it goes!

---

As a side note: since you're learning python and considering the code you pasted before your first edit, I would just like to emphasize how important indentation is in python. A change of indentation can completely change the meaning of your code, and it is very important that you understand how and why certain blocks are indented.

Comment: Thank you for response! I'm very thankful for your help. I tried to make a print. So it's printing "2" when there is a 2 faces and "1" when just 1